# Bootstrap-like Tags input in Flex TextInput

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, apache-flex

Is there a way to do something similar to [Boostrap's tags input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) in flex (in spark:TextInput)? I need to select an item from a combobox and then it should be put in something like a tag.

Comment: There is no default component the works like Boostrap's tags input in Flex, you will have to implement a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spark:TextInput not have such capability.
You can create custom skin with horizontal layout for spark list, like that(you should change only dataGroup layout in skin, as the basis take spark.skins.spark.ListSkin)

```
<s:Scroller left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"
            id="scroller" minViewportInset="1" hasFocusableChildren="false">
    <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup"
                 itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout gap="0"
                                horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="5" />
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Then create custom itemRenderer which looks like tag.
And put yout tags to the list's dataProvider.